# Sending collective data from a Spinner to a different Activity

Tags: java, android, spinner, toast

I have an activity with several spinners which shows varying products. At the moment, my spinners display a toast message displaying the item that was selected from the list. However, I would like to extend the functionality so instead it displays the value associated with the product.

For example: User selects 'apple' and the Toast displays '130kcal'. At the end of the activity there will be a button which adds all of the amounts up and stores them in a different intent for later viewing.

I get I would have to somehow store the values in variables associated with the spinner item ID's(maybe?) and then call a toast based on that, but I'm not sure how.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Code:

```
package com.example.c3347115app;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyMeals extends Activity {

Spinner sp;
public int apple = 130;
public int toast1 = 200;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_meals);

    sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
            int arg2, long arg3) {

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), sp.getSelectedItem().toString(), 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            //Do nothing
    }
});

}
```

xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MyMeals" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/my_meals" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/breakfast" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/breakfast_array"
    android:prompt="@string/breakfast_title" /> 

<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/snack"/>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/breakfast_array"
    android:prompt="@string/breakfast_title" />

<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/lunch" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/breakfast_array"
    android:prompt="@string/breakfast_title" />

<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/snack1"/>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner4"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/breakfast_array"
    android:prompt="@string/breakfast_title" />

 <TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/dinner"/> 

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner5"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/breakfast_array"
    android:prompt="@string/breakfast_title" />"

</LinearLayout>
```

strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string name="app_name">Eat Right</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="title_activity_mot_d">MotD</string>
<string name="title_activity_meal_plans">MealPlans</string>
<string name="title_activity_your_meals">YourMeals</string>
<string name="title_activity_progress">Progress</string>


<string name="motd">Meal of the Day</string>
<string name="my_meals">My Meals</string>
<string name="meal_plans">Meal Plans</string>
<string name="my_progress">My Progress</string>


<string name="breakfast">Breakfast</string>
<string name="breakfast_title">Choose Breakfast</string>
<string name="snack">Snack</string>
<string name="snack_title">Choose Snack</string>
<string name="lunch">Lunch</string>
<string name="lunch_title">Choose Lunch</string>
<string name="snack1">Snack</string>
<string name="snack1_title">Choose Second Snack</string>
<string name="dinner">Dinner</string>
<string name="dinner_title">Choose Dinner</string>

<string-array name="breakfast_array">
    <item>Cereal</item>
    <item>1 slice toast</item>
    <item>2 slice toast</item>
    <item>Eggs and bacon</item>
    <item>Eggs and sausage</item>
    <item>Eggs, sausage and bacon</item>
    <item>Yoghurt</item>
    <item>Apple</item>
</string-array>


</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

where u r displaying toast u can also save the amount in any int or float and can sum up them on button click and can send via intent.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you. Can you clarify in more detail?

Comment: have u applied onItemSelected on spinner.their u can save setted values or at the end getSelectedItem on each spinner and sum to any var or provide me your class i'll demonstrate u how to do..

Comment: I've added in the code now if you can help me through that that would be great :)

Comment: public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
            int arg2, long arg3) {

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), sp.getSelectedItem().toString(), 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } sp.getSelectedItem().toString() value take in a string then parse to int and do this thing for all spinner with applying onItemSelected on all spinner